# Вернуть действие по умолчанию для клавиши "Sleep" и прочих мультемедийных клавиш

Tags: linux, kde, sleep

Если в systemsettings переопределить действие стандартной глобальной клавиши, в моём случае "Sleep", то как потом вернуть обратно на эту клавишу действие по умолчанию?

Comment: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/fundamentals/shortcuts.html#shortcuts-reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О, нащёл! :-) В "Компонент KDE:" нужно выбрать "Служба KDE".
[image: Sleep]